# when do we omit the article in an OF-phrase?

Tags: articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

When do we omit the definite article THE at the beginning of a phrase and for what reason? 
*Removal of skin* or *the removal of skin*. Could someone give some examples?

Comment: I'll start the ball rolling by saying that titles (_The Nawab of Pataudi_) and set phrases (_the back of beyond_) are rarely used without the definite article, especially in formal registers. With non-collocational strings, the situation seems more idiosyncratic. 'The taking of hostages' seems the preferred form; perhaps this is true for most/all gerunds. 'The' would probably be preferred when the phrase introduced a non-follow-on statement ...

Comment: I am inclined to say it depends on where you place the phrase in a sentence. Like: _"Removal of skin tags is a relatively easy procedure"_ vs _"Mohs micrographic surgery is an advanced technique for the removal of skin cancer"_. [Source for the second example](http://www.uchospitals.edu/specialties/cancer/skin/mohs.html)

Comment: But if we have a very specific situation? Is it obligatory to use some article? For example, the removal of skin tags is a must.. or would I have to say a removal of skin tags?

Comment: @LasciviousGrace I think _... technique for removal of skin cancer_ would be equally acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I would fall back to the general rule for the usage of definite articles. It doesn't really matter whether the article appears at the start of a sentence or not. Just keep in mind whether you are referring to a particular instance of a class or not:

> Removal of skin is painful.

Here, we are referring to the act of removing skin, in the general.

> The removal of skin had Jack crying in pain for days.

Here, we are referring to a specific instance of a class – the removal of Jack's skin.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not the whole story: see Lascivious Grace's examples.

Comment: I cannot find them...sorry

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: True. But, the question was specifically about omitting the definite article at the beginning of a phrase. So.

Comment: So? You _do_ know what a phrase is?